# nested array ruby TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-3

```
def get_att(webinar_id)
  finalArray = []
  api_service = ApiService.new
  response = api_service.get_attendees(webinar_id)
  json = JSON.parse(response.body)

  for x in json['_embedded']['attendeeParticipationResponses']
    first_name = json['_embedded']['attendeeParticipationResponses'][x]['firstName']
    last_name = json['_embedded']['attendeeParticipationResponses'][x]['lastName']
    email = json['_embedded']['attendeeParticipationResponses'][x]['email']
    finalArray << [first_name, last_name, email]
  end

  # x = 2
  # first_name = json['_embedded']['attendeeParticipationResponses'][x]['firstName']
  # last_name = json['_embedded']['attendeeParticipationResponses'][x]['lastName']
  # email = json['_embedded']['attendeeParticipationResponses'][x]['email']
  # finalArray << [first_name, last_name, email]

  Rails.logger.info(finalArray)
end
```

The idea is to return an array of arrays with all of the people and their 3 tags.

I know that the JSON parse data is working because the commented out code works perfectly and I can change `x` assignment and it runs. The for loop also works because it counts 15 responses in `json['_embedded']['attendeeParticipationResponses']` when I add a counter. So I know the 15 people are there and I can add them one by one into the final array (which I got to hold multiple arrays by the way), but for some reason the second I put it in the for loop I get the weird error which fully reads:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer from /Users/josh/Documents/GitHub/schools_health/lib/go_to_webinar/to_pipeline.rb:19:in `[]'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I fixed it! It was a syntax issue.

I come from more of a Java background and the loop syntax for ruby makes `x` an object. I thought it would contain the array index. I fixed it by changing the references inside the loop from:

```
first_name = json['_embedded']['attendeeParticipationResponses'][x]['firstName']
```

to:

```
first_name = x['firstName']
```

Comment: You could make the code a lot more elegant by using [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and [`Hash#values_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at). Have a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/5d8c3928e54c3909e33bb6f4e97d09f8).